# SVG element height not scaling past 150px

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I've seen several posts online about how the default size of the height of an SVG is 150px, but I can't find a definitive answer on how to get around this.

```
<body>
<svg width='100%' height='100%'></svg>
</body>
```

All I want to do is scale the SVG to the size of the window, but at 1% or 1000%, height is always 150px.

Comment: try changing the height of body `body{height:100vh;}`

Comment: Also, open your SVG in a text editor and make sure to remove the viewbox and any fixed heights or widths that is defines. Then save the svg and try again. You want all of that defined in your CSS, not in the SVGs DOM if you want to control it eternally.

Comment: Chiller you beautiful bastard. Thanks for the help. Both of you.

Comment: Korgue's advice is not entriely valid. You can't redefine a viewBox using CSS.

Answer (score 2):

There are already some answers in the comment but i'll put one here. The issue is that if your parent container doesn't have it's own height value, it's only as large as the content within it. If your SVG is 150px by default, your body is 150px give the svg just enough space. 100% of 150 is... well, 150. Chiller's `height:100vh;` will expand your body to the height of your window, making your svg that large as well. You can scale it by placing your SVG in a div or giving the SVG fixed dimensions.